# Java -for loop only repeating last value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have an Array to hold the value from DB. If I try with some default data it working fine but if I get value from DB, its only showing last value.

Default Data;

```
MenuList menu_data [] = new MenuList[]{};
menu_data  = new MenuList[]
{
new MenuList("test","test1") ,      
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") ,  
new MenuList("test","test1") 
};
```

Value from DB,

```
MenuList menu_data [] = new MenuList[]{};
List<Menu> profiles = db.getAllContacts();
for (Menu cn : profiles) {
menu_data  = new MenuList[]
{
new MenuList(cn.getmenuname(), cn.getmenuprice())  
};
}
```

How do I get all the value from DB.

Comment: have you tried `menu_data = profiles.toArray()`?

Comment: in my profiles I have few values like menu,price,Vege,Time,Date...I just want to show menu and price....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<MenuList> menulists = new ArrayList<MenuList>();
for (Menu cn : db.getAllContacts())
    menulists.add(new MenuList(cn.getmenuname(), cn.getmenuprice()));
MenuList[] menu_data = menulists.toArray(new MenuList[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Everytime you go through the loop, you are creating a new array. Hence, only the last value is available. Please try the following

```
menu_data  = new MenuList[profiles.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < menu_data.length; i++) {
    Menu cn = profiles.get(i);
    menu_data[i] = new MenuList(cn.getmenuname(), cn.getmenuprice());  
}
```

Comment: you need to declare and initialize `i` variable: `int i = 0`; and in the loop: ` menu_data[i++] = ...`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Missed that completely! Thanks

Comment: it throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Comment: @chinna_82 Which line is the exception thrown at?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Menu> profiles = db.getAllContacts();
int numProfiles = profiles.size();
MenuList[] menu_data = new MenuList[numProfiles];
for (int i = 0; i < numProfiles; i++) {
    Menu cn = profiles.get(i);
    menu_data[i] = new MenuList(cn.getmenuname(), cn.getmenuprice());
}
```

Comment: it throw 2 error.. 1st. Cannot define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided..2nd  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Comment: Sorry, I meant to just create it instead of using the initializer.  Fixed.  If length = 0 then the `for` loop body will not be executed at all.